# Django-dilla "Unknown command: 'dilla'"

Tags: python, django, django-1.4, django-commands

I'm unable to make django-dilla work with my django1.4 project. I've installed django-dilla through pip and I can import it properly from shell.

```
>>import dilla
>>dilla.__file__
'/Users/misterte/.envs/python2.7-Django1.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_dilla-0.2beta-py2.7.egg/dilla/__init__.py'
```

I've added it to my installed apps just before south, and ran my syncdb command.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    [...]
    'dilla',
    'south',
)
```

But when I try to call it, it won't work.

```
$python manage.py dilla --cycles=30
Unknown command: 'dilla'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
$python manage.py run_dilla --cycles=30
Unknown command: 'run_dilla'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Then, of course, no sub commands are present under the [dilla] app when running help.

```
$python manage.py help | grep dilla
# emptiness :(
```

Any clues? Does dilla work in the django1.4 layout?

Thanks!

A.

Comment: If you're managing migrations using south my guess is you would also need to migrate tables associated with dilla. You might want to confirm that at botton section when you run syncdb. (If needed run python manage.py migrate dilla)

Comment: No, dilla has no models associated with it. Only managers. But your suggestion made me realize the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem.

For some reason pip is not installing dilla under site packages. I can import dilla and the egg is present under my site-packages folder, but further inspection showed that there were no packages under dilla.

Solution: copy dilla into you folder manually. I downloaded it from [github](http://aerosol.github.io/django-dilla/).

Also, I recommend you copy it to a 'vendor' subfolder in your project. This way you avoid probably having to do the same hack in your production server. Then you import app as 'vendor.dilla' in your installed apps.

A.